# Excluding several IP-ranges in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've been trying to wrap my head around excluding four IP-ranges (Edit: It is only the third octet that is ranging from 1-128. The fourth are "static" as detailed below) in Google Analytics. My skills for regular expression, which Google Analytics can utilize, isn't the greatest. I was hoping to get some assistance here on how to structure my regexp so that it does what I want.

The IP-ranges I am looking to exclude are:

> 10.130.1.0 - 10.130.128.0,
>
> 10.130.1.99 - 10.130.128.99
>
> 10.132.1.0 - 10.132.128.0
>
> 10.132.1.1 - 10.132.128.1.

As you can see, there are some static portions and some more "dynamic".

The full regexp I created looks like this (separated it to be easier to read, but it is actually on one line):

> ^10.130.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8])).0|
>
> 10.130.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8])).99|
>
> 10.132.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8])).0|
>
> 10.132.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8])).1$

Am I doing it right? I haven't really fully grasped the grouping `()`, or if I need to group together each separate part of the different ranges, like `(10\.130\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-1][0-9]|2[0-8]))\.0)`, or keep it like it is, without the `()`?

Am I grouping it correctly and is this a good way to do this?

Comment: those ip ranges look a bit weird - they overlap. You'll have a simpler regex if you define your ip ranges so they do not overlap, as they are infact only 2 ranges.

Comment: @AD7six - Hm, I don't think they overlap...

Comment: @acheong87 10.130.1.0 < 10.130.1.99 < 10.130.128.0. There are either typos, or two ranges `10.130.1.0 - 10.130.128.99` and `10.132.1.0 - 10.132.128.1`.

Comment: @AD7six - I think what the poster means though are ranges of the third octet only, not the fourth. I agree that typically when IP ranges are expressed as above, you'd include the fourth octet ranges as well. But the context seems different here.

Comment: @AD7six - Hm, you're right. I guess such third-octet ranges don't really make sense from a networking perspective. Strange.

Comment: Some clarification: It is only the third octet that is in a range. I agree that it seems strange from a networking perspective, but those are the ranges I was instructed to use. The fourth octet in the adresses above are "static" (they differ in the 4 ranges, but they don't go from 1-99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it right, the way you have it. I can't tell whether you're trying to match the inclusion or the exclusion—I assume the exclusion—as long as you know the `^` is an *anchor*, matching a beginning-of-string, not the *negation operator* which only exists inside *character classes*.

I think this is easier to read, though:

```
^10\.130\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[01][0-9]|12[0-8])\.(0|99)$

^10\.132\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[01][0-9]|12[0-8])\.(0|1)$
```

Comment: Note that these two regexes do not act like a range, they will capture only a fraction of the IP addresses mentioned in the question. e.g. they would not match the ip address 10.130.1.2 - because of the last digit

Comment: @AD7six - See my comment on the question. I think OP means to match 10.130.1.0, 10.130.2.0, 10.130.3.0, ..., 10.130.128.0, _not_ 10.130.1.1 or 10.130.1.2. I guess my brain implicitly agreed with your original protest: that if we're including ranges of the fourth octet, this question doesn't make sense / seems strange.

Comment: I *think* that the above expression fulfills what I am looking to do, and it is alot more cleaner then mine :) Also, I am using this as both an inclusion and exclusion. The exclusion part in GA is alot easier, but for the inclusion, which is the one I am struggling with, feels a bit harder as it needs to be on one line.

Comment: And yes, I am aware of ^ and $. I want to match the whole string from beginning to end. Not sure if it helps with accuracy, but in my mind it does :)

Comment: +1 for answering exactly what was asked - note that the dot's in the regex should be escaped - and possibly, since google analytics isn't going to be feeding invalid ip addresses to the pattern both, `[0-9]` and `[1-9]` could be replaced with `\d` (also applies to my own answer, though I kept the char-range syntax for easier readability).

Comment: @AD7six How would \d be used in this case? And how do I make my \d the same gray as yours in the comments?

Comment: @AD7six - Fixed, thanks. I agree, I tried to replace the `[0-9]`s with `\d` but the result was less readable.

Comment: @MrSponge - In most flavors of regular expressions, `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`. According to http://www.cheatography.com/jay-taylor/cheat-sheets/google-analytics-regular-expressions/, this includes Google Analytics.

Comment: @AD7six Thanks. Really good cheat sheet. I'll make sure to bookmark that one.

Answer (score 4):

### Determine the ip addresses that apply

The ip address ranges in the question are confused, the intention is *probably* :

```
10.130.1.0 - 10.130.128.99
10.132.1.0 - 10.132.128.1
```

This answer is based on the assumption that this is the case - I've read the comments about only wanting to apply a range to the third octet but in all probability that's a misunderstanding (alternatively that really is the intention - but it's unlikely to be so for any future readers).

### As a regular expression

The IP ranges can be expressed as:

```
10.130.1.0 - 10.130.127.254*
10.130.128.0 - 10.130.128.99
10.132.1.0 - 10.132.127.254*
10.132.128.0 - 10.132.128.1
```

Note that the two ranges marked with a star cover the whole range of the last octet, as such in a pattern any digit qualifies. Therefore in pseudo regex what is required is:

```
10.130.[1 to 127].*
10.130.128.[0 to 99]
10.132.[1 to 127].*
10.132.128.[0 or 1]
```

each of those ranges needs to be a regular expression which handles the digits that make up those numbers.

#### 1 to 127

There are one to three digits, with some complexity when treated with a regex - however it can be broken down like so:

```
[1-9] # 1-9
[0-9]{2} # 10-99
1[0-1][0-9] # 100 - 119
12[0-7] # 120-127
```

Or:

```
([1-9]|[0-9]{2}|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7])
```

#### 0 to 99

This one is easy since it's one or two digits:

```
[0-9]{1,2}
```

#### 0 or 1

Also easy:

```
[0-1]
```

### All together:

Therefore as a complete regex the full range can be expressed as:

```
^10\.(
    130\.([1-9]|[0-9]{2}|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7])\.[0-9]{1,3} |
    130\.128\.[0-9]{1,2} |
    132\.([1-9]|[0-9]{2}|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7])\.[0-9]{1,3} |
    132\.128\.[0-1]
)$
```

Note that it's a good idea to anchor the regex to the end of the string, otherwise an ip address such as

```
10.130.128.111
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is outside the defined range would match, with the last digit being ignored.

### Simplifying assumptions

Google isn't likely to submit invalid ip addresses, so given that it's possible to make some simplification's to the above regex - `[0-9]` and `[1-9]` can be treated equally meaning that this:

```
[1-9] # 1-9
[0-9]{2} # 10-99
```

becomes:

```
[0-9]{1,2} # 1-99, one or two digits
```

The regex can therefore be expressed as a slightly simpler:

```
^10\.(
    130\.([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7])\.[0-9]{1,3} |
    130\.128\.[0-9]{1,2} |
    132\.([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7])\.[0-9]{1,3} |
    132\.128\.[0-1]
)$
```

Further, `[0-9]` can be written as `\d` which then makes the regex slightly less verbose::

```
^10\.(
    130\.(\d{1,2}|1[0-1]\d|12[0-7])\.\d{1,3} |
    130\.128\.\d{1,2} |
    132\.(\d{1,2}|1[0-1]\d|12[0-7])\.\d{1,3} |
    132\.128\.[0-1]
)$
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, AD7six. It was a very comprehensive answer and it also goes through some different options which helped me learn more. I can't upvote yet though as my old account wasn't retrievable.

Comment: +1 for answering the question that made seeming sense, and having the skepticism to hold out as long as one could in the absence of clarification. And for pointing out my mistakes.